# Problema com programa para reverter audio WAV em C

Tags: c, áudio

Estou fazendo um programa para reverter(deixar de traz para frente) um áudio WAV dado como entrada, porém meu programa para de funcionar e não consigo achar onde estou errando.

Segue meu código:

cabeçalho:

```
            #ifndef WAV_H_
            #define WAV_H_

            #include <stdint.h>

            typedef unsigned char byte;

            typedef struct riff{
                char chunkID[4];
                uint32_t chunkSize;
                char format[4];
            }__attribute__((packed))RIFF;

            typedef struct fmt{
                char subchunkID[4];
                uint32_t subchunkSize;
                uint16_t audioFormat;
                uint16_t numChannels;
                uint32_t sampleRate;
                uint32_t byteRate;
                uint16_t blockAlign;
                uint16_t bitsPerSample;
            }__attribute__((packed))FMT;

            typedef struct data{
                char subChunk2ID[4];
                uint32_t subChunk2Size;

            }__attribute__((packed)) DATA;

            typedef byte RAW_DATA;


            #endif /* WAV_H_ */
```

main:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #include "wav.h"

    int main(int argc, char **argv){
      if(argv[1] == "\0"){
        exit(-1);
      }
      char *infile_name = argv[1];

      FILE *infile =  fopen(infile_name, "rb");

      if (infile == NULL) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file %s", infile_name);
          exit(1);
      }

      RIFF *riff_infile = NULL;
      FMT *fmt_infile = NULL;
      DATA *data_infile = NULL;

      riff_infile = (RIFF *) malloc(sizeof(RIFF));
      fmt_infile = (FMT *) malloc(sizeof(FMT));
      data_infile = (DATA *) malloc(sizeof(DATA));

      if (riff_infile == NULL || fmt_infile == NULL || data_infile == NULL){
        printf("System out of memory!\n");
        exit(-1);
      }

      fread(riff_infile, sizeof(RIFF), 1, infile);
      fread(fmt_infile, sizeof(FMT), 1, infile);
      fread(data_infile, sizeof(DATA), 1, infile);

      RAW_DATA *samples_infile = NULL;
      samples_infile = (RAW_DATA *) malloc(sizeof(RAW_DATA) * ((data_infile->subChunk2Size)));

      if (samples_infile == NULL){
        printf("System out of memory!\n");
        exit(-1);
      }

      fread(samples_infile, fmt_infile->bitsPerSample/8, (data_infile->subChunk2Size), infile);

      riff_infile->chunkID[4]='\0';
      fmt_infile->subchunkID[4]='\0';

      FILE *outfile;
      outfile = fopen("myFile", "w");

      RAW_DATA *samples_outfile = NULL;
      fmt_infile->subchunkSize = 16;
      samples_outfile= (RAW_DATA *) malloc(sizeof(RAW_DATA) * ((data_infile->subChunk2Size)));

      int max = (data_infile->subChunk2Size);
      int j=0;

      while(max >= 0){
          samples_outfile[j] = samples_infile[max];
          max--;
          j++;
      }

      fwrite(riff_infile, sizeof(RIFF), 1, outfile);
      fwrite(fmt_infile, sizeof(FMT), 1, outfile);
      fwrite(data_infile, sizeof(DATA), 1, outfile);
      fwrite(samples_outfile, sizeof(RAW_DATA) * fmt_infile->bitsPerSample/8, (data_infile->subChunk2Size), outfile);

      free(riff_infile);
      free(fmt_infile);
      free(data_infile);
      free(samples_infile);
      free(samples_outfile);

      fclose(infile);

      return 1;

    }
```

Comment: `outfile = fopen("myFile", "w");` - Acho que era para você usar `"wb"`.

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Eu estava testando o programa no windows e resolvi testá-lo no linux e para minha surpresa funcionou. Não sei qual o problema na execução com o windows...

Comment: Estranho. Não tem muito sentido isso não funcionar no windows.